# How to initiate a spark component with non-default skin state?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, skin, flex-spark

I am creating a Custom Button extending Spark Button class. The skin class of my button supports 2 skin states, 'Up' and 'Down'.

The custom button works properly when I changes Button's skin states via some measures like dropdown etc. But when I tries to initialise custom button with a skin state, via 'currentState' directives, it throws a run time error

```
ArgumentError: Undefined state 'down'.
```

Below is some part of my custom skin class

```
<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
<!-- host component -->
<fx:Metadata>
    [HostComponent("components.CustomButton")]
</fx:Metadata>

<s:states>
    <s:State name="up" />
    <s:State name="down" />
</s:states>
    ....
    ....
</s:Skin>
```

Custom Button class has not much and it just extending Button class plus having some [SkinState] and [SkinPart] directives.

Below is the way I want to use my Custom Button

```
<comp:CustomButton skinClass="skins.CustomButtonSkin" currentState="down"/>
```

Thanks,
Sumit

Comment: Depends on your implementation of CustomButton, so it's hard to say what to do. That said, the `currentState` of the skin and the `currentState` of the host component are not the same thing, which is why you get that error.

Comment: Usually the component you create the skin for has a state and the skin has its own states. Usually you keep them in sync, but this is not mandatory. So I guess you have given your skin a "down" state but CustomButton doesn't have such a state. So if you so myCustomButtonInstance.currentState = "down"; you get the error you are getting. Have a look at this page: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS460ee381960520ad-2811830c121e9107ecb-7ff9.html#WS03d33b8076db57b9-a120b14121ef5f63a3-7fff

Comment: Ohh..now I got it. I created a `Style` property for my custom button and then using it to setting correct Skin State to my skin class from `getCurrentSkinState` method. Thanks @RIAstar and @chrisdutz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a `Style` property for my custom button and then using it to setting correct Skin State to my skin class from `getCurrentSkinState` method